# What code to use related to PHP Encoding?

Tags: php, encoding

How do I interpret some characters into their proper form in PHP?

For example, the string is `\u00c9rwin` but PHP print it as `Ã‰rwin`, and the correct form must be `Érwin`

What is the proper PHP code for this? I am pretty sure this is not an HTML entity, or is it?

P.S. no encoding was declared on the PHP file

Comment: Tutorial on charsets & PHP here: http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/charsets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this in header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

or:

```
<?php header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Look into `utf8_encode` and `utf8_decode`.
It's important as well to go UTF8 across the whole stack. What that means is that your database connection should be using UTF8 ([here's how in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html)), your HTTP Content-Type should be returning UTF8 (see mgraph's example below) and you should also be setting it in the meta tag so that there is no need to encode/decode at all as you're using **the same charset everywhere**.